# Max MSP ADC to trigger samples

Tags: max-msp, sound-design

has anyone got a simple solution on how to take the signal from the ADC (inbuilt microphone) and have the signal trigger a sample in Max MSP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just quickly made a patch. Hope this helps.

DL @

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7skelt7rulb4avg/MSP%20ADC%20Trigger.maxpat

Answer (score 4):

One way to approach this could be to use the meter~ object attached to a float and use an if statement to send a bang that would trigger a clip when it exceeds a certain level.

Comment: exactly what I was going to recommend.

Comment: +1 for that. The [slide] object is also useful for smoothing the float output of [meter~].

Answer (score 0):

Was also going to say what powblock said.